# Audio.get vk после очередных обновлений

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Итак, метод `audio.get`, который возвращает плейлист пользователя. В какой-то момент он начал выдергивать аудиозаписи, которые доступны только для веб-версии.

Поковырялся в WindowsPhone приложении, достал оттуда их `client_id`. При таком раскладе все работает, как надо - вытаскивается плейлист, но без ссылок. У них свой личный API или что это?

В конечном итоге, мне нужно добиться работы WindowsPhone приложения: 
Возвращать *полный* плейлист без ссылок.Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение очень простое - вытащить данные из веб морды. Возвращает всю нужную информацию, но без ссылок на аудио записи.

Ход:
В консоли найти audio.php и посмотреть, какой запрос идёт туда и сформировать аналогичный. Требуется авторизация в платформе. Ответ возвращает в json - крайне грязный результат без названия полей и с какой-то системной информацией, назначение которой я не знаю.